# How to downcase the first character of a string?

Tags: python, string

There is a function to capitalize a string, I would like to be able to change the first character of a string to be sure it will be lowercase.

How can I do that in Python?

Comment: Are you sure s.lower() is not what you want?
Otherwise you could get weird results such as 'hELLO'.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

One-liner which handles empty strings and `None`:

```
func = lambda s: s[:1].lower() + s[1:] if s else ''

>>> func(None)
>>> ''
>>> func('')
>>> ''
>>> func('MARTINEAU')
>>> 'mARTINEAU'
```

Comment: I find lambdas to be much less readable than a regular function definition.  Do you really think it's worth it just to save a single line?

Comment: @MarkRansom: Quite the contrary, I find this very readable. YMMV.

Comment: Yes I'll grant you that YMMV.  But since I'm in a complainy mood, does it bother you that this function returns an empty string for *any* falsey input even if it isn't a string?  For example `0` or `[]` or `False`.

Comment: @Mark: Not much because I don't expect anyone to be trying to use on those kind of values (besides that, type-checking is unpythonic).

Comment: @MarkRansom: The deleted below uses `return s[0].lower() + s[1:] if s else s`

Comment: @serv-inc not at all clear on what you're trying to tell me.

Comment: @MarkRansom : you complained about returning an empty string for any falsey input. This could be fixed by using the `if s else s` below instead of `if s else ''` .

Comment: @serv-inc I wouldn't consider that an improvement.  Thanks for trying though.

Comment: @MarkRansom I totally agree with you. Not because of readability but because this is a PITA to debug when people make if statements and for loops (or both at the same time!) on the same line. I use to think it was clean. Now I just role my eyes.

Answer (score 48):

```
s = "Bobby tables"
s = s[0].lower() + s[1:]
```

Comment: Is there a way this can be edited to lowercase more than just the first letter? I thought I could do something like `s = s[10].lower() + s[11:]` but this still only gave me the first letter lowercased instead of the first 10.

Comment: @christylynn002: you need to use slicing. s = s[:11].lower() + s[11:]

Answer (score 22):

```
def first_lower(s):
   if len(s) == 0:
      return s
   else:
      return s[0].lower() + s[1:]

print first_lower("HELLO")  # Prints "hELLO"
print first_lower("")       # Doesn't crash  :-)
```

Comment: your original answer was perfect, but `len(s) == 0` is just bizzare.

Comment: @SilentGhost: It's one of a million valid ways to say what it's saying.  It's related to the problem that it's there to solve - you mustn't run the code if the string is zero length, so that's explicitly what I'm testing for.  I could have said `if not s:` but that doesn't represent the problem quite so well.

Comment: I'd prefer `if not len(s)` personally, but that's just being nit-picky

Comment: @Richie: you're solving a problem that OP doesn't have and are doing it in a C-style, to add insult to injury.

Comment: @SilentGhost: Am I misunderstanding you? Are you really saying that it's better to provide an answer that fires an exception when called with an empty string than an answer that works in that case?

Comment: @Richie: I'm saying that this is not what OP asks, and we should trust him to be able to assemble simple if statement on his own.

Comment: @SilentGhost: None of us knows how experienced the OP is.  It's easy to miss corner cases when someone provides you with code that demonstrably works.  I'd rather err on the side of caution than provide an answer that I know will fail in a common case.

Comment: Thorough answers like these tend to educate the asker better than concise ones. Given that the asker is asking this, it is reasonable to point out the corner case. It is an extra tidbit of knowledge that the asker can take away from the answer and keep in mind when he's making similar functions in the future.

Comment: @RichieHindle: What about the case when `s == None`? Wouldn't the first `if` condition throw and error?

Comment: @Manoj: Well, yes, but you have to draw the line somewhere... s.capitalize() will also fail if s is None (or an integer, or a badger :-)

Comment: @RichieHindle: The test for zero length strings can be omitted if one uses slicing: `s[:1].lower() + s[1:]` also works for empty strings. I agree that there is no need to handle None.

Comment: @RichieHindle: Better to ask forgiveness etc. You are right :)

Answer (score 10):

Interestingly, none of these answers does *exactly* the opposite of `capitalize()`.  For example, `capitalize('abC')` returns `Abc` rather than `AbC`.  If you want the opposite of `capitalize()`, you need something like:

```
def uncapitalize(s):
  if len(s) > 0:
    s = s[0].lower() + s[1:].upper()
  return s
```

Comment: I don't think it's the intention of the OP

Comment: @Xavier:  You're probably right, but it's interesting that `capitalize` mucks with the rest of the string.

Answer (score 8):

Simplest way:

```
>>> mystring = 'ABCDE'
>>> mystring[0].lower() + mystring[1:]
'aBCDE'
>>>
```

**Update**

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840843/how-to-downcase-the-first-character-of-a-string-in-python/3840854#3840854) (by @RichieHindle) for a more foolproof solution, including handling empty strings. That answer doesn't handle `None` though, so here is my take:

```
>>> def first_lower(s):
   if not s: # Added to handle case where s == None
   return 
   else:
      return s[0].lower() + s[1:]

>>> first_lower(None)
>>> first_lower("HELLO")
'hELLO'
>>> first_lower("")
>>>
```

Comment: Aye. I'd also like to know why this was down voted. If there is a mistake I'll be the first to want to know.

Comment: There is a mistake - if you pass in an empty string you get None back, since you have an empty return statement.  That is unintuitive and bound to lead to bugs in the calling code.

Comment: The second code snippet's indentation is not correct

Answer (score 8):

No need to handle special cases (and I think the symmetry is more Pythonic):

```
def uncapitalize(s):
    return s[:1].lower() + s[1:].upper()
```

Comment: There shouldn't be `.upper()` in your function.

Comment: It's prone to error, check length of s before performing operation

Comment: @harshil9968 one of the really nice things about slices in Python is that they work even when the indexes are out of bounds.  You might get an empty string, but it still works.

Answer (score 0):

I'd write it this way:

```
def first_lower(s):
    if s == "":
        return s
    return s[0].lower() + s[1:]
```

This has the (relative) merit that it will throw an error if you inadvertently pass it something that isn't a string, like `None` or an empty list.

Comment: how will it raise an exception that the other solutions wouldn't? The first opportunity for an error is when you slice and all of the other ones do that anyways.

Comment: Not so - the accepted answer, for instance, doesn't raise an exception if you pass it an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

This duplicate [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47272742/how-do-i-convert-the-first-letter-of-every-word-in-a-list-from-upper-case-to-low) lead me here.

If you've a list of strings like the one shown below

```
l = ['SentMessage', 'DeliverySucceeded', 'DeliveryFailed']
```

Then, to convert the first letter of all items in the list, you can use

```
l = [x[0].lower() + x[1:] for x in l]
```

Output

```
['sentMessage', 'deliverySucceeded', 'deliveryFailed']
```

Comment: You don't even need to use enumerate in that case: `l = [x[0].lower() + x[1:] for x in list(l)]`

Answer (score 0):

**pip install `pydash`** first.

```
import pydash  # pip install pydash

assert pydash.lower_first("WriteLine") == "writeLine"
```

https://github.com/dgilland/pydash

https://pydash.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

https://pypi.org/project/pydash/

Comment: That is a classic case, where introducing dependencies for a simple oneliner doesn't make sense at all.