# how to change the case of first letter of a string?

Tags: python, string, uppercase

```
s = ['my', 'name']
```

I want to change the 1st letter of each element in to Upper Case.

```
s = ['My', 'Name']
```

Answer (score 56):

Both .capitalize() and .title(), changes the other letters in the string to lower case.

Here is a simple function that only changes the first letter to upper case, and leaves the rest unchanged.

```
def upcase_first_letter(s):
    return s[0].upper() + s[1:]
```

Comment: This doesn't change the 1st letter of _each element_ in the list shown in the OP's question.

Comment: Though LC, `[i[0].upper() + i[1:] for i in s]`

Comment: this code will  give an index error for empty strings. Use instead `return s[:1].upper() + s[1:]`

Answer (score 30):

You can use the [capitalize()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.capitalize) method:

```
s = ['my', 'name']
s = [item.capitalize() for item in s]
print s  # print(s) in Python 3
```

This will print:

```
['My', 'Name']
```

Comment: capitalize does not do what OP asks. capitalize will also make lower cases non-first letters

Comment: yeah, this answer is misleading: `'naMe'.capitalize() == 'Name'`

Answer (score 14):

You can use `'my'.title()` which will return `'My'`.

To get over the complete list, simply map over it like this:

```
>>> map(lambda x: x.title(), s)
['My', 'Name']
```

Actually, `.title()` makes all words start with uppercase. If you want to strictly limit it the first letter, use `capitalize()` instead. (This makes a difference for example in 'this word' being changed to either `This Word` or `This word`)

Comment: and also the difference between Frank's and Frank'S -- as is noted here http://op.to/How.To.Capitalize.First.Letter+

Comment: Also, `str.title` is an easier way to specify `lambda x : x.title()`.

Answer (score 6):

It probably doesn't matter, but you might want to use this instead of the `capitalize()` or `title()` string methods because, in addition to uppercasing the first letter, they also lowercase the rest of the string (and this doesn't):

```
s = map(lambda e: e[:1].upper() + e[1:] if e else '', s)
```

**Note:** In Python 3, you'd need to use:

```
s = list(map(lambda e: e[:1].upper() + e[1:] if e else '', s))
```

because `map()` returns an iterator that applies function to every item of iterable instead of a `list` as it did in Python 2 (so you have to turn it into one yourself).

Comment: +1: nice catch; however, why the `if s else ''` expression? To avoid a concatenation of empty strings? I believe it's premature optimization.

Comment: @ΤΖΩΤΖΙΟΥ: Thanks. That part is there mainly because I just tweaked my answer to a similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840843/how-to-downcase-the-first-character-of-a-string-in-python/3847369#3847369). I prefer to think of it as defensive programming since it can handle a list element being `None` (so, no, it's not there because of a concerned about the empty string case being less than optimal).

Comment: I think handling `None` like this is bad practice. I would rather have an exception raised in this case than have the (possibly wrong) blank string silently passed.

Comment: @MindVirus: If you want an exception for `None` values you could use `lambda e: e[:1].upper() + e[1:] if e or e is None else ''`.

Comment: @martineau, my whole gripe is that you're attempting to circumvent duck typing. The correct solution, in my opinion, is `lambda e: e[:1].upper() + e[1:]`.

Comment: @virtualxtc: If you look the original question, you'd see that `s` is the list of strings being modified. The `e` is just the argument name of one of the elements from it that the `map()` function will pass to the `lambda` function which is defined in the expression.

Comment: Ok, thanks, the variables are more clear enough now (it's my 4th day using python). However, I'm intrigued, but confused by this discussion about  `e is None`.

Comment: @virtualxtc: It has to do with the handling of any elements of the list (expected to all be strings) that are empty `""` or have the value `None`. Both of those kind of values have a truthiness of `False` in Python when they're used as a simple boolean/conditional value like the expression in an `if` statement. There's also a related issue being discussed about whether values like that should be dealt-with silently/automatically or raise exceptions should one be encountered.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
for i in range(len(s)):
   s[i]=s[i].capitalize()
print s
```

Comment: You don't need `temp`, it doesn't doing anything and so is the same as `list[i]=list[i].capitalize()` -- which would only work if the OP's list named `s` was renamed `list` -- but that would be a bad practice because doing so would hide the built-in function/type of the same name. Not sure why the trailing comma on the print statement was put there...

Comment: it was typo mistake to put comma there.