# how do I convert the first letter of every word in a list from upper case to lower case?

Tags: python, bash, notepad++

how do I convert the first letter of each of the below from upper case to lowere case?

For example `SentMessage` would become `sentMessage` and `NotAttemptedCreditLimitReached` would become `notAttemptedCreditLimitReached` ... etc

list of words below. They are just in a text file.

```
SentMessage
DeliverySucceeded
DeliveryFailed
DeliveryTimedOut
NotAttemptedCreditLimitReached
NotAttemptedChargingFailure
SubscriptionFailed
SentReportSMDeliveryStatus
FailedToSendReportSMDeliveryStatus
ReportSMSucceeded
ReportSMFailed
```

Was looking at doing it notepadd++ initially, but open to other suggestions bash/python ... etc

---

### EDIT1 - the solution

```
$ cat testw
SentMessage
DeliverySucceeded
DeliveryFailed
DeliveryTimedOut
NotAttemptedCreditLimitReached
NotAttemptedChargingFailure
SubscriptionFailed
SentReportSMDeliveryStatus
FailedToSendReportSMDeliveryStatus
ReportSMSucceeded
ReportSMFailed
$ sed -i 's/[A-Z]/\L&/' testw
$ cat testw
sentMessage
deliverySucceeded
deliveryFailed
deliveryTimedOut
notAttemptedCreditLimitReached
notAttemptedChargingFailure
subscriptionFailed
sentReportSMDeliveryStatus
failedToSendReportSMDeliveryStatus
reportSMSucceeded
reportSMFailed
```

Comment: Do some research first: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43705853/how-to-capitalize-first-letter-of-each-line-in-bash and Google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have gnu sed then use:

```
sed -i 's/[A-Z]/\L&/' file
```

- `[A-Z]` will match first upper case letter
- `&` is back-reference of matched string by pattern (in this case single upper case letter)
- `\L` converts given back-reference to lowercase