# How can I convert into lower case the first letter of each word in a pandas colum?

Tags: python, pandas, nlp

I would like how to convert the first letter of each word in this column:

```
Test
There is a cat UNDER the table 
The pen is working WELL.
```

Into lower case, in order to have

```
Test
    there is a cat uNDER the table 
    the pen is working wELL.
```

I know there is capitalize() but I would need a function which does the opposite.

Many thanks

Please note that the strings are within a column.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840843/how-to-downcase-the-first-character-of-a-string

Comment: It would be the case of strings within column. I think it would be just necessary to iterate through the rows within the column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is a builtin for this, but I could be mistaken. This is however quite easy to do with string comprehension!.

```
" ".join(i[0].lower()+i[1:] for i in line.split(" "))
```

Where `line` is each individual line.

Comment: This should be the case of strings. However I would be interested in strings within a column. I think it would need just toniterate through rows within the column

Answer (score 1):

According to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840843/how-to-downcase-the-first-character-of-a-string) you can do :

```
>>> func = lambda s: s[:1].lower() + s[1:] if s else ''
>>> sent = "There is a cat UNDER the table "
>>> res = " ".join(list(map(func , sent.split())))
>>> res
'there is a cat uNDER the table'
```

Comment: With strings should be easy. With strings in columns aI think it should be necessary to iterate through rows within the column

Comment: Is this for strings in a column?

Comment: ok ,, so you hve dataframe or something right... you can always iterate over the column ..

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.str.lower`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.lower.html), [`.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and `' '.join`:

```
s=df.Test.str.split()
df.Test=s.str[0].str.lower()+' '+s.str[1:].agg(' '.join)
```

---

Same as spliting the words with `.str.split` and then modifying with `apply`:

```
df.Test=df.Test.str.split().apply(lambda x: [x[0].lower()]+x[1:] ).agg(' '.join)
```

---

Both outputs:

```
df

                             Test
0  there is a cat UNDER the table
1        the pen is working WELL.
```